# sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant failure user hasn't approved this consumer - cross machine

Tags: scratch-org, oauth, jwt

This is related to [How to open a scratch org created in another machine](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205829/how-to-open-a-scratch-org-created-in-another-machine) but posed somewhat differently

**Given:**

- DevHub with Connected App defined using a digital certificate

  - Correct Oauth scopes defined: (`api, web, refresh_token, offline_access`)
  - Policy: `Admin approved users are pre-authorized` with System Administrator profile configured
  - Connected App Consumer Key of `MYCONSUMERKEY`
  - Private key file: `server.key`

**When**

Machine 1

```
Authorizes to the DevHub using sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid MYCONSUMERKEY \
     --username [MY_DEVHUB_LOGIN] \
     --jwtkeyfile ./certs/server.key \
     --setdefaultdevhubusername -a DevHub

Create scratch org: sfdx force:org:create edition=Developer 
   yielding username machine1@example.com
```

Machine 2

```
Authorizes to the scratch org created in Machine 1 using sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid MYCONSUMERKEY \
     --username machine1@example.com \
     --jwtkeyfile ./certs/server.key \
     -a Machine1ScratchOrg
```

This all works fine as per [Wade Wegner's Authenticate to Your Scratch Org Using JWT OAuth](http://www.wadewegner.com/2018/01/jwt-oauth-with-scratch-orgs/) or the [Authorize an Org Using the JWT-Based Flow SFDX Official Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm)

**But if Machine 1**

```
Authorizes to the DevHub using the Web Flow
Creates a scratch org yielding username machine1.1@example.com
```

Then Machine 2 can not find that scratch org, even using the `force:auth:jwt:grant` to authorize against the dev hub and again to authorize the scratch org (w/ username `machine1.1@example.com`)

> My question is basically WHY?  It seems as if there's a "chain of
> custody" model wherein if you want to find a scratch org created on a
> different machine, then all machines need to use the JWT OAuth flow.
> Merely possessing the creds (secret key to the cert, consumerkey) to
> access the Connected App on the DevHub is not sufficient to find all
> the scratch orgs created for that DevHub.